# Who pioneered the use of Laughing Kookaburra birds to create the impression of a jungle setting?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history, sound-effects

I was sent a link to the first video below and it immediately sent me back to my childhood watching reruns of what were already old films on Sunday afternoon television.

I'm sure I've heard this bird's vocalization in many old films, but I'd like to know who first used the sound effect of a Laughing Kookaburra bird for the purpose of creating the impression of a jungle setting?

Comment: I cannot do this justice as an answer, nor it is truly conclusive - but some guy had a heck of a time tracing this back to a Tarzan movie from 1938 - please read http://soundandthefoley.com/2013/05/30/that-jungle-sound/ and the research in 
http://soundandthefoley.com/2013/08/27/of-tarzan-and-kookaburras/

Comment: @Tetsujin excellent! I'll give them a thorough read. Yes this actually sounds familiar, it may have indeed been an old Tarzan movie I'm remembering seeing. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a US site at a guess. I'm UK & no issues here. I'f you're using a VPN, try without; some sites actively block VPNs.

Comment: @Tetsujin oh it's working now and I'm enjoying them. I'm overseas and sometimes strange things happen.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [Is the “'dolphin call” from the TV show Flipper and The Bourne Identity (2002) “actually a modified kookaburra call”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/110058/45856)

Comment: Although not strictly in a jungle setting, I did find that the laughing Kookaburra can be heard in a series of Australian newsreels that date back to 1929.