# Is the "dolphin call" from the TV show Flipper and The Bourne Identity (2002) actually a modified kookaburra call?

Tags: sound-effects, the-bourne-identity, flipper

A comment below [Who pioneered the use of Laughing Kookaburra birds to create the impression of a jungle setting?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/110049/45856) links to a The Sound and the Foley blogpost [That Jungle Sound](http://soundandthefoley.com/2013/05/30/that-jungle-sound/) which explores the use of this bird's "laugh" to create an impression of being in a jungle setting.

At the bottom of this post are lists of movies and television shows in which recordings of Kookaburra are employed. One of them caught my eye:

> In [Flipper (the 1964 TV series)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipper_%281964_TV_series%29), the titular dolphin’s famous cry is actually a modified kookaburra call. (!) (This “dolphin call” can also be heard at the very end of [The Bourne Identity (2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0258463/).)

I recall sitting in the theatre at the end of The Bourne Identity and immediately thinking "*Flipper!*" But what I find surprising here is the claim that "This 'dolphin call' is "actually a modified kookaburra call."

**Question:** Is this true? Is there any information to support this? It's hard to imagine there was technology available to do such a thing in the 1960's, nor a need to.

Comment: By technology you mean computers? Before that there were analog means to edit audio / video.

Comment: @Luciano to make a bird sound like a dolphin? In 1964? How?

Comment: Audio mixers, sound boards, tape editing? Speed up / slow down, re-record... Lots of things were possible before computers were popular / cheap.

Comment: A distinction: they didn't use a kookaburra call to sound like a dolphin - they used a kookaburra call to sound like what audiences would think sounds like a dolphin.

Comment: Not an official source, but some more info you could explore further (and yes, kookaburras sped up and higher pitched) : https://soundeffects.fandom.com/wiki/Hollywoodedge,_Dolphin_Chirps_Vocal_PE024601

Comment: @racraman no answers are yet forthcoming, I think that even a tentative answer would be helpful and if nobody complained I might accept it.